# Hilbert transform in python not giving desired output

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I am very new to signal processing, so please bear with me.

I am trying to generate a complex signal of the form exp(i*phi*), given the real part of the signal, which is cos(phi). Here, *phi* is the simulated phase, which is a fourth order polynomial.

For this, I gave the real signal(which is cos(phi)) as input to the **signal.hilbert()** method from the scipy module.
The python code used is given here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import cmath
from scipy import signal

x = np.arange(0.0,256,1)                 
phi = 10**-7 *(x-128)**4   # phase of fourth order/ quartic phase
plt.plot(x,phi)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('phase')

#Since the phase is simulated here, the complex signal can be defined as:
complex_signal =  [cmath.exp(1j*a)for a in phi] 

#Assume we only have the real part of the signal which is cos(phi) and the goal is to 
#generate the complex signal (of the form exp(i*phi) from the real signal

real_signal = np.cos(phi)

#Using Hilbert transform to generate analytic signal

analytic_signal = signal.hilbert(real_signal)

plt.plot(x,np.real(complex_signal),'r--',x,np.real(analytic_signal))
plt.legend(['Re(complex_signal)','Re(analytic_signal)']) 

plt.plot(x,np.imag(complex_signal),'r--',x,np.imag(analytic_signal))
plt.legend(['Im(complex_signal)','Im(analytic_signal)']) #see figure 1
```

[image]

From figure 1, it is evident that the Hilbert transform of the real signal is not equivalent to sin(phi). Is this because Hilbert transform is applicable when the phase variation is linear and here it is quartic? And more importantly, is there a way to get the sin(phi) part of the signal to build up the complex signal of the form exp(i*phi) from the real part of the signal?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: The Hilbert transform just doesn't do what you want.  It will turn a sum of cosines into as sum of sines with the same coefficients, but that won't turn cos(f(x)) into sin(f(x)) for arbitrary f.  What you're saying you want also doesn't seem to be useful, so I think this is an X Y problem.  You should probably ask about your true purpose.

Comment: Does the paper recommend the Hilbert transform for this purpose?  It sounds like it could work.  If the phenomenon is essentially a frequency modulation of a complex carrier, then  you can use the Hilbert transform to get the complex signal from the real part by cancelling out the negative frequencies.  This is only accurate for band-limited signals, though -- the modulation has to be gentle enough that the positive-frequency products don't mix with the negative-frequency products.  Maybe your test signal isn't realistic?

Comment: @MattTimmermans, I am trying to implement the pseudo-Wigner Ville algorithm based on this paper: https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-58-16-4420&id=413113.  The algorithm works on complex signal. The paper deals with holographic interferometry, which gives complex output by default. I have successfully implemented the algorithm on simulated complex signals. But, I am working in an interferometric method called photoelasticity whose output is a fringe pattern image(i.e, real part of the signal). So, I need to perform real to complex signal conversion to implement the algorithm.

Comment: "*From figure 1, it is evident that the Hilbert transform of the real signal is not equivalent to sin(phi)*", actually if the signal is made of a sum of cos, then the Hilbert transform is the sum of the same components as sin. More generally it's the sum of the components shifted by -90°. [Here is a sample with a signal made of 3 cosines of various frequencies and phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko0mL.png). The imaginary part of the `scipy.hilbert` is found equal to the sum of the same components shifted by -90°.

Answer (score 0):

Note the end of you signal shows a closer match than the beginning. That might be because the Hilbert filter you are using has an impulse response of non-zero length, and you have not waited past the impulse response for the filter output to stabilize.  Try prefixing your data with some amount of (continuous in all derivatives) data, until the Hilbert filter output becomes stable enough before the results are needed.  It's possible padding past the end of your may also be required, depending on how the Hilbert is implemented.